# Apply jQuery action only to clicked button

Tags: jquery

```
$(".btn-atc").click(function () {
    $(".btn-atc span").removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".btn-atc span").removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
    }, 1500);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvv0fqv/)

I've made the above so that a button can have a loading like effect when its been clicked to let the user know the action has been completed (blue and red are stand ins for a cart icon and a loading icon).  When a button is clicked, it applies function to every button on the page.  What do I have to do to only perform the action on the button being pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it right, just change a little bit in your code, using $(this):-

```
  $(".btn-atc").click(function () {
    var ref=$(this);
 $(ref).find("span").removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
   setTimeout(function () {
    $(ref).find("span").removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
   }, 1500);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`, it refers to element which invoke the event.

```
$(".btn-atc").click(function () {
    $("span", this).removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
    var span = $("span", this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        span.removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
    }, 1500);
});
```

You can also use `$(this).find('span')` in place of `$("span", this)`

Comment: That triggers the change to red, but it doesn't trigger back to blue after the timeout http://jsfiddle.net/xpvv0fqv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try using "this"

```
$(".btn-atc").click(function () {
    $(this).next('span').removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).next('span').removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to trigger any of the actions unfortunately http://jsfiddle.net/xpvv0fqv/2/